# hibernate map<key, set<value>>

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have the following tables:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")    
Event
    --id
    --name

@Entity
@Table(name = "state")    
State
    --id
    --name

@Entity
@Table(name = "action")    
Action
    --id
    --name
@Entity
@Table(name = "state_event_action")
    StateEventAction
--id
--state_id
--event_id
--action_id
```

I would like in `state` class to get `map<key, set<value>>` of `Map<Event, set<StateEventAction>>`

How can I do it in Hibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to recieve Map of sets, it means that there are several actions for each (state_id, event_id) actions. So you have wrong entity's mappings. It should be

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "state_event_action") 
StateEventAction 
--id 
--state_id 
--event_id 
--Set<action> actions
```

In this case you can write :

```
@Entity @Table(name = "state")     
State 
    --id 
    --name 
 Map<Event,StateEventAction> eventActions;
```

Answer (score 6):

> I would like in state class to get `map<key, Set<value>>` of `Map<Event, Set<StateEventAction>>`

Hibernate does not support collection of collections such as List of Lists, Map of Sets, etc out of the box. But you could implement your own `UserCollectionType` to add support for this kind of data structure. This [blog post](http://blog.xebia.com/2007/10/05/mapping-multimaps-with-hibernate/) shows how to do so  using the [`MultiMap`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) implementation from Apache commons.

My suggestion would be to use a similar approach, but maybe to prefer the generified [`Multimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from Google Guava.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to first query all the StateEventAction objects for the state then write your own code to first create a set for the event if not already created then add the StateEventAction obejct to the set.

```
State state = // < the state object;
Query q = Session.createQuery("from StateEventAction sea inner join fetch sea.event where sea.state = :state");
q.setEntity("state", state);

Map<Event, Set<StateEventAction>> map = new HashMap<Event, Set<StateEventAction>>();

for(Iterator itr = q.list().iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
   StateEventAction sea = itr.next();
   Event event = sea.getEvent();
   Set<StateEventAction> theSet = map.get(event);
   if(theSet == null) {
      theSet = new HashSet<StateEventAction>();
      map.put(event, theSet);
   }
   theSet.add(sea);
}
```